# Russian roulette statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following probabilily problem.

"You're playing a game of Russian roulette, the revolver has 6 chambers in which you put 3 bullets completely random. What is the probability that all bullets are next to each other?"

The solution says 0.3

I have no clue how to start with this problem or which kind of distribution to choose. Can I get feedback on this problem?

Thanks, 
Ter

Comment: Avoid no-clue question. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the bullets are interchangeable, the number of ways we can load 3 bullets into a six-shooter is "6 choose 3", which is 20. Of those 20 configurations, we can see that there are exactly 6 that have all the bullets adjacent - one with chambers 1,2,3 loaded, one with chambers 2,3,4, and so on, including the ones that wrap around like 6,1,2.

With 20 equiprobable configurations and 6 that satisfy the criterion, the odds of randomly getting one is 6/20, or 0.3.

You can also arrive at this answer by sequentially picking positions. It doesn't matter where the first bullet goes. For the second bullet, you have a 1/5 chance of putting it one chamber to the left, and then you have a 2/4 chance of putting the third bullet on either side of the first two, for a total chance of 2/20. You could also put the second bullet two chambers to the left of the first one with 1/5 chance, but that only gives you a 1/4 chance of putting the third bullet between the first two, for a total chance of 1/20. These probabilities are exactly mirrored by considering bullets placed on the right instead of the left, so your overall chance is 2 x (2/20 + 1/20), which is again 6/20, or 0.3.